# Order by in LINQ with group by and join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using following code to display data to a Kendo Grid.
My problem is, I want "SALENO" column to be sorted but its not working. Date wise sorting is displayed

```
        var query =
        from s in db.Sales
        where s.TYPE == "DOLLAR"
        group s by s.SALENO into sg
        join a in db.Accounts
        on sg.FirstOrDefault().PARTY equals a.ID
        join b in db.Accounts
        on sg.FirstOrDefault().BROKER equals b.ID
        orderby sg.FirstOrDefault().SALENO
        select new Sale_List
        {
            ID = sg.FirstOrDefault().ID,
            SALENO = sg.FirstOrDefault().SALENO,
            PARTY = a.ACCOUNTNAME,
            BROKER = b.ACCOUNTNAME,
            DATE = sg.FirstOrDefault().DATE,
            TOTAL = sg.Sum(m=>m.TOTAL),
            CARET = sg.Sum(m=>m.CARET),
            PRICE=sg.Average(m=>m.PRICE),
            TERMS=sg.FirstOrDefault().TERMS
        };
        DataSourceResult result = query.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Description**

I am selling diamonds to certain party with broker in between. Sale details is saved in a table and accounts(party,broker) details are saved in a seperate table. There are two tables in this query. I first get data from `SALE` table and then group it by `SALENO`. I am doing grouping because a single sale no can have multiple sale entries from different sources. Then I join sale partyid with `accounts` ID(PK) and same for broker. This way I get the data combined in `Sale_List`

```
ID        SALENO        DATE        CARET        PRICE        PARTY        BROKER
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1             2020-01-21  102          89           3            5
2         2             2020-01-19  88.5         103          4            5
3         2             2020-01-19  50           102          4            5
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve interpreting your query, can you explain with words the result you are trying to get?

Comment: It is really strange to do the `group by` before the `join`s - what is the purpose of that?

Comment: @octavioccl I have added description.

Comment: @NetMage I have added description

Comment: "a single sale no can have multiple sale entries from different sources" - what does this mean?

Comment: yeah, I have the same question, I was expecting an account has multiple sales

Comment: @NetMage, For example `SALENO 2` has two entries, one entry is from different polished packet(labeled P1) and second entry is from another polished packet(labeled P2). So `SALENO 2` contains mixed polished diamonds that is going on sale.

Comment: So the "no" is a mistake: "a single sale **no** can have multiple sale entries from different sources" ?